# Database connectivity checking on Rails

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-server-2008

I am completely new to Rails, and my first task was to connect to a MSSQL DB.

I followed this [This tutorial](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds) for setting up the adapter, and changed the information in database.yml the development part to my information.

How do I test if I'm actually connected? If I can see that I have concrete results, I would be able to progress further with Rails migration, but for now, I'm stuck in this initial step and have to idea how to advance further.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a migration:

on console: rails g migration test

then go to folder db>migrate>###.test.rb

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :test do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :number

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

then go back to your console and run:

rake db:migrate

if it run successfuly then you should have created a table in your DB

Comment: I did all you said, it did succeed, but I don't see the new table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rails console` to launch the rails console which will interact with your database.

Then try `a = Test.create("name", 1)` if that returns successful, and you recieve something like
`# <Test :name=>"name"...>` then it ran successfully, and your database is correctly configured.

http://railsonedge.blogspot.com/2008/05/intro-to-rails-console.html offers some decent help

Comment: Undefined method 'create' for Test:Module. Does that mean I still created it, tho?

Comment: this is assuming that `Test` is the name of your model. i was more-so extending @RodrigoZurek's answer

Comment: I did perform his method first. And both of you are directing me to each other's answer.

Comment: well - this is all depending on what your model is named :P  we are directing to each other because we are both correct, and we have no idea the schematic of what you are dealing with. the tutorial doesn't seem to have anything.  expand your `models/` directory. what model are you trying to test?

Comment: That's sort of the thing - I didn't know what the starting point for everything was, so I thought connecting and testing a DB connection would be logical. I was hoping for some cheap Rails trick that bypasses its functionality and let's me do a simple Select *, and if that succeeds, I can start do proper RoR DB migrating and create models for my tables.